# Flask-SQLAlchemy filters and operators

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, operators, flask-sqlalchemy

Flask-SQLAlchemy gives the option to filter a query. There are a wide number of ways you can filter a query - the examples the Flask-SQLAlchemy docs give:

```
User.query.filter_by(username='peter') # Returns all users named 'peter'
User.query.filter(User.email.endswith('@example.com')) # Returns all users with emails ending in '@example.com'
```

I also found this for one-to-many relationships:

```
User.query.filter(User.addresses.any(address=address)) # Returns all users who have a particular address listed as one of their addresses
```

Questions:

- Does anyone know what filters are actually available to be used? I can't find a list of filters anywhere in the documentation, which makes it rather hard to query databases.
- In particular, what filter would I use to check if a user's email is contained within a particular set of email addresses?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For a list of filters check [SQLAlchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html)

> > what filter would I use to check if a user's email is contained within a particular set of email addresses?

Columns have a `.in_()` method to use in query. So something like:

```
res = User.query.filter(User.email.in_(('x1@dom1.com', 'x2@dom2.com')))
```

[Here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/sqlelement.html) you can find the list of column method for expressions.

Comment: For more attributes like `in_` and `endswith`, see [Common Filter Operators](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html#common-filter-operators) and [ColumnOperators](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators).

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks! :D And that `._in` method seems exactly what I want right now, too.